# Implementing Facepile

Tags: facebook

**For some reason I'm unable to implement Facepile** onto my Wordpress site. I've actually tried a time before this and had no such luck, I know everyone will point me to the documentation, but I've read through it, and entered my credentials through the 'Facebook Developers Facepile screen'.

I inserted my facebook page's URL, Yes there were a lot of people that liked the page. I've also tried inserting the full stand alone website URL. I've also tried inserting a 'personal facebook page link' as opposed to a page you like. I've tried pasting the generating iFrame, using HTML5, and adding custom actions as stated and tried ustilizing an online tutorial.

I'd prefer to drag the iFrame on my sidebar. But if I had to use a WP plugin I'd need one with shortcodes as my theme isn't widget ready.

Even at the Facepile screen I cannot get the generator / preview to even load it. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit, EG - Why won't this work?**

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/facepile.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.osmproduction.com%2FRIF%2F&amp;action&amp;size=small&amp;max_rows=1&amp;width=300&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;appId=380729875300495" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you are getting? What problem are you having when you try one (or more) of these techniques?

Comment: Thanks for the response. For one; I can't even get a preview to show up at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/ - Using this URL (Click for Actual). What is an action I should define for this to work properly?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/72sagha <- URL sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Yes there were a lot of people that liked the page. "

I think you're confusing FacePile with the Like plugins.

Facepile (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/) is only for website pages where you have an action associated with them via your application.  An action is a pairing of verb noun separated by a colon.  So if you have a custom action that can get published to Facebook from your site say:  test-drive:truck, and if some user has had that action published to their facebook stream, then it should show up in the Facepile plugin.

Like plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) is for when someone has liked you website page.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still very confused as to how to implement this. I'm trying to do it with a page (Very popular page). I've created an APP ID for it as well. Could you send me a stand alone demo or code where I can swap out my page's credentials?